# php mail() subject keeps showing as Apache Server

Tags: php, apache2

I am trying to get to grips with the php mail() function. Whenever I send a mail, it keeps showing in the subject 'Apache Server' and not the address that I have specified in the code. I have also changed the sendmail_from in the php.ini, restared the server, but still the same subject line. How can I change this to show the email address specified in the code. It is a FQDN.

```
sendmail_from   admin@mydomain.co.uk
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i


    $id = $_SESSION['kt_name_usr'];
    $to = "example@somewhere.com";
    $subject = "New Request.";
    $headers = "From: admin@mydomain.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body = "<html><body><b>testing system for requests not a real request</b></body></html>";
    $body .= $id;
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Comment: You are using `$header`. but actually the variable is `$headers`

Comment: Good spot. Thanks. Why you not put as answer so I can upvote you? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using the variable `$header` in [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. But actually the variable name is `$headers`. Edit that like the following:

```
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```